# optimization of mysql explain output

Tags: mysql, sql

i have just run mysql explain to check one query and got surprised to see that it has to check more than 250000 records to sort the result however i have index for where clause and whatever mysql explain is giving i am completely agree as that much new row has been added so how to sort out this issue .mysql table structure is

```
 tableA is a forum where users can post the content 

  id         userid       created       title

  1          3            12232         xyz
  2          etc...............
```

my mysql query is

```
  explain SELECT * from tableA   where userid='2' order by created desc limit 3
```

output of this explain query is

```
  id    select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
  1     SIMPLE  tableA  ref     userid  userid  4   const   275216  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

my worrie is how to reduce this to 3-4 as i am interested in displaying only three result but mysql is searching 275216 records before displaying the output . as 275216 records has been created after userid 2 has posted in forum but what is the solution to tell mysql that look only for specific data so that it can search the result from very small set of rows i want maximum 20-30 rows mysql should search to server 3 rows

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
SELECT * from tableA  FORCE INDEX (userid) where userid=2 order by created desc limit 3
```

Comment: tried and the output was 274487 userid indexexonly userid shall i combine userid and created in one index

Comment: Is `userid` int or a varchar?

Comment: if it will use index then also it will show after that much rows as that much row has been added by users

Comment: @Reck more than 10 million

Comment: Then I think it might be working as expected. I'm not an expert on db optimization by  long shot, but here's what seems to be going on. Since multiple users can have the same userid, the database is doing an index range scan. This means that the database has to scan through all index leaf pages that may contain at least one entry where userid = 3. Obviously this number is going to be much larger than the total number os rows that have userid = 3. In order to get around this, and assuming that no two users have the same value in the created column, you can use a (userid, created) column.

Comment: I meant an (userid, created) index, not a column :). Edit: it might be good to compare the performance of such an index against that of an (created, userid) index as well.